# <c:if test> is not working for the dynamic value comparision

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jstl

I wanted test the whether the 'obj.icon' is true or false and based on that I need to append the active class for the 'IconFill' span. For me the 'obj.icon' value is coming dynamically from the service and it is printing the true value.

I tried the following way which is not working as expected. can any one suggest whats wrong in my code.

```
 ...
 +'<c:if test="'+obj.icon+' == true "><c:set var="classActive" value="active" /></c:if>' +
'<span id="IconFill" class="optionicons ${classActive}"></span>' +
```

Comment: why are the `<c:if>` tags wrapped in single quotes ? Are you doing this in JavaScript ? `<c:if>` is part of JSTL core library and are resolved on the server side in your JSP file. Adding them as strings will not render them because they're not recognized by your browser. You can add them directly in your JSP file and span will be updated while translating the JSP to HTML page

Comment: Yes, I am doing this in javascript. I am appending this dynamically based on some other result

Comment: If that's the case, you can add your desired class to your span using `classList` or using `addClass()` in jQuery

Comment: Open the problematic page in webbrowser, rightclick it and choose *View Page Source*, stare at JSP-generated HTML output around the given snippet as long as until you get the adrenaline rush of an "Eureka!".